# jQuery: How to determine if one or more textboxes are empty

Tags: jquery, html

Suppose I've got a set of textboxes of the form:

```
<input class="member" type="text" name="integrantes[]" />
```

For validation, I need to make sure all of these textboxes contain a value, and display an error if not.

My current idea is basically to set the value outside, a la:

```
var oneEmpty = false;
$(".member").each(function() { oneEmpty = oneEmpty || $(this).val() == "" });
if (oneEmpty) { etc }
```

However, it's not particularly elegant. Therefore, is there a better way to pull it off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply filter out all the inputs that are not empty, and check if you have any inputs left:

```
var empties = $('.member').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).val()) == '';
});
if (empties.length) { /* Error! */ }
```

Comment: Filter was exactly the function I was looking for, but somehow missed between everything else. Thanks.

Comment: man that's elegant. took me about a minute to figure out how it works; cant wait till I can write code that way by second nature

Answer (score 4):

If you are using jquery validation you could just put a required class on your textbox input and it would validate for you. [jQuery Validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

```
<input class="member" type="text" name="integrantes[]" class="required" />
```

Comment: Given the scope of the project (it's basically homework) and the amount of validation I have (2+x fields), that felt like shooting fish with a rocket launcher. (Plus, last time I checked Validate still didn't work with 1.5.1. Obviously that's not the case anymore).

Comment: While this is generally the better answer, Box9 gave exactly what I was looking for, so I guess this is a case where the best answer isn't the same as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Kyte I would recommend you use [jQuery validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and apply a required class on all text inputs I also I imagine that you may want it for other stuff too

Comment: Likewise.  I'm sure this is a duplicate though.

Comment: @Kyle Rogers my answer or the question ?